# report an exactly same bug using Issues tab on github

Tags: github

How do I mention on the "Issues" page that I am facing the same problem?
There is no "Affects Me too" button anywhere on github.

For e.g. how do I express my concern on this page without adding any comment.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21621

Writing a "Me too" comment does not add any value to bug report. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "add reaction emoji" button at top right; if anyone did so, it appears at the bottom of that comment, and you can click the emoji to add yourself to it too. In particular, adding a thumbs up reaction is a common way to say "me too".

Comment: Thanks. Done that. How do I search and return all bugs those affect me? Can I search all "thumbs up"?

Comment: Dunno. I am not sure there is such a mechanism... this is more informal than not, I suppose.